# How to retrieve a part of a string based on an expression (php)

Tags: php

Im in need of a little bit of PHP help. I have a string variable which contains somewhere in it "ID: 174". It could also have in it "ID: 1736553". I'm quite new to these things and wondered, how can I get the ID number from this string? I don't know what the ID is and need to retrieve it.

Thanks in advance,
Kris

Answer (score 0):

Try [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
$pattern = '/ID: ([0-9]+)/';
preg_match($pattern, $your_string, $matches)
```

What you want will be in `$matches[1]`

Answer (score 0):

If you know that ID will be composed of only integers and that it will appear only once in the string, you can use something like this:

```
preg_match('/ID:\s*(\d+)/', $string, $matches);
$the_id = $matches[1];
```

You can read more about [`preg_match()` in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) but I'm guessing you'll first want a tutorial on regular expressions if you don't already know them fairly well.  You might find something less dry with some Google searching, but if all else fails, the PHP manual has [a PCRE section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) (PCRE is a variant of regular expressions that was popularized by the Perl language).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach. It's character/digit independent. The rule here is it catches any character set other than a space.

```
$str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor ID  3dk45 sit amet.';
preg_match('/(?<=\bID\b)\s*(.+?)+\b/',$str,$matches);
$id = preg_replace('/\s/','',$matches[0]);
```