# Get substring between two markers in a specific line of a file

Tags: php, substring, text-files, text-extraction, file-read

I'm trying to select a specific section of a specific line within a file.

For instance, I want to isolate the first line of text from a file and get the numeric value of `rate` without the trailing `kbit` text.

Sample file contents:

```
tc class add dev br-lan parent 1:1 classid 1:2 htb rate 100kbit ceil 100kbit
tc class add dev br-lan parent 1:1 classid 1:3 htb rate 200kbit ceil 200kbit
tc class add dev br-lan parent 1:1 classid 1:4 htb rate 300kbit ceil 300kbit
```

I would like to select the data between "rate " (notice the space after rate) and "kbit" based on the line number, then store it as a variable.

**Expected Result:**

Effectively, I would like to retrieve the results based on, for example; line 1:

```
100
```

Then store this value as a variable.

This won't work with substr, as shown here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php as the length of the integer retrieved may not always be the same length.

File path:

```
../etc/init.d/bandwidthlimiters/rulestest
```

Comment: Perhaps you could grab the number using a regex expression and `preg_match`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561161/how-to-retrieve-a-part-of-a-string-based-on-an-expression-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$output_arr=array();
$handle = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {

    $i=1;
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

    $test_string=$line;
    $test_string=str_replace(" htb rate ","@@",$test_string);
    $test_string=str_replace("kbit ceil ","@@",$test_string);

    $tmp = explode("@@", $test_string);
    array_push($output_arr,$tmp[1]);
    $i++;
   }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
} 

echo $output_arr[2]

?>
```

Comment: how would I implement this using lines from a file within a specified location?

Comment: open the file as below$handle



$handle = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        // 
        // place the above in this line
  // if need output of each line then create a array in the starting and keep on adding each output tothat array
        // so that in the end you will get an array which would contain all the required values
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}

Comment: Have edited the answer for your comfort(I have not tried running the code)

Comment: this is echoed: "Line 1 result:" with no result. Note, I have the correct file location as am using elsewhere.

Comment: Hi Reconnected, I tried the code(plz see, I have slightly edited it further). It is working for me. I used same test case which you provided in the question

Comment: it now prints the following: Line 1 result: 1
Line 2 result: 1
Line 3 result: 1, it does not show the expected value of 100, 200 and 300, how do I modify the code to only display a line I specify and provide the actual value rather than the number of matches?

Comment: "how do I modify the code to only display a line I specify? " ?? Could you please elaborate it more with exact requirement. Do you want to specify a limit on number of lines you reading from file or want to ignore few lines? Please explain in detail

Comment: I want to grab the "100" from the first line, store it as a variable and echo it, as shown in the "expected result" of the question

Comment: Done. Please check the answer now. Hope that helps else sorry for wasting your time

Comment: Just kept a break statement in the loop so that it comes out of the loop after reading the first line.

Comment: This works as I would like! Thanks! However, it does not allow me to retrieve the result of any other line in the file, I.e: line 2 or 3, any idea?

Comment: I assumed it was a case of modifying "$required_output=$tmp[1]; to "$required_output=$tmp[2];", however this does not work

Comment: I have done this for you now... just place right index on $output_arr[2] variable as per your requirement and I hope this is what you were looking for

Answer (score 1):

Try this hope it will work fine.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$lines=file("path/of/file.txt");//get the content of file as an array of lines
$result=array();
foreach($lines as $lineNo=>$line)
{
    preg_match('/rate\s*\K[\d]+/', $line,$matches);
    $result[$lineNo+1]=$matches[0];
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: at the moment this prints "Array ( [1] => )" rather than the expected "100", any thoughts as to why this may be?

Answer (score 1):

This task requires two basic subtasks:

1. Accessing a specified line in a file and
2. Extracting a substring from a string.

For subtask #1, there is good advice at [PHP: Read Specific Line From File](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5775452/2943403) which explains that a developer can choose succinct syntax with `file()` to read relatively small files or use an `SplFileObject` with `seek()` to efficiently target one line.

1. With `file()`:

   ```
   $lineNumber = 1;
   $line = file('your/path/to/file.txt')[$lineNumber - 1];
   ```
2. With `SplFileObject`:

   ```
   $lineNumber = 1;
   $spl = new SplFileObject('your/path/to/file.txt'); // temporarily locks file
   $line = $spl->seek($lineNumber - 1)->current();
   $spl = null; // unlock file
   ```

For subtask #2, targetting the desired substring can be done a myriad of ways depending on the sought characters, preceeding characters, delimiters in the text, etc.  I'll list a couple basic techniques.

1. Explode on delimiting spaces and cast as an integer to trim `kbit` characters by consequence: [Demo](https://3v4l.org/o6Nhc)

   ```
   $rate = (int) explode(' ', $line)[11];
   ```
2. Regular expression: [Demo](https://3v4l.org/nUA57)

   ```
   $rate = preg_replace('/.* rate (\d+).*/', '$1', $line);
   ```

No matter which combination of techniques you choose, there is certainly no need to implement hacky string replacements to introduce placeholders before extracting the desired text.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the issue:

```
<?php
$lines = file("../etc/init.d/bandwidthlimiters/rulestest");
$results = array();
foreach($lines as $num=>$line) {
    preg_match("/([0-9]+)\s*kbit/i", $str, $out);
    if(isset($out[1])) $results[$num] = $out[1];
}
```

Now,

$results = array with results where index is the line number corresponding each result

Comment: how would I implement this using lines from a file within a specified location?

Comment: No result, not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Verifies there's a ("rate ") string before and ("kbit") string ahead, not consuming either of them:

```
/(?<=rate\s)\d+(?=kbit)/
```

Code:

```
<?php
$lines=file("file.txt");
$result=array();
foreach($lines as $oneline)
{
    preg_match('/(?<=rate\s)\d+(?=kbit)/', $oneline, $matches);
    $result[]=$matches[0];
}
?>
```

file.txt:

```
tc class add dev br-lan parent 1:1 classid 1:2 htb rate 100kbit ceil 100kbit
tc class add dev br-lan parent 1:1 classid 1:3 htb rate 200kbit ceil 200kbit
tc class add dev br-lan parent 1:1 classid 1:4 htb rate 300kbit ceil 300kbit
```

$result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 100
    [1] => 200
    [2] => 300
)
```

Comment: echo $result; echo $result[1] returns no result

Comment: I've tried it and it works, can you try echoing the file content is the foreach loop to verify you're successfully pulling it's content?

Comment: file content is there and I saw a flash of the result on refresh, strange?

Comment: you're still getting an empty $result array?